# Using System.js in HTML file to invoke a typescript class method

Tags: typescript, systemjs

I'm trying out Typescript and System.js. The Typescript compiler is running with the -w flag.

I'd like to invoke a method when the page loads, I can import play, but not access it with 'then':

HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.41/system.js'> </script>
  <script>
    System.import('./play.js').then(function(play) { 
      play.start(); 
    });
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

play.ts file:

```
export class Play {
  start() {
    alert('hello...');
  }
}
```

I get the error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: play.start is not a function`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.import` result is a module, not a class. Returned module has references to all things exported from it, so you can get `Play` class as `play.Play`, but to call `start()` method you have to create an object of that class first, using `new`. Something like this should work:

```
  <script>
    System.import('./play.js').then(function(play) { 
      var player = new play.Play();
      player.start(); 
    });
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: thanks - think I will change the parameter name to 'namespace' or something